# Outlook 2010 starts flashing

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, dynamics-crm

I'm running Outlook 2010 with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011, and it runs fine for a bit, but then the whole window will just start quickly flashing as if I'm quickly clicking on and off of the window. The only way to get it to stop is to kill it in Task Manager. It only happens when I'm using the CRM and it effects all open windows. I've checked the Event Viewer and didn't see any errors or warnings for Outlook. Below are my machine specs:

```
    Operating System
        Windows 7 Professional 64-bit SP1
    CPU
        Intel Core i5 2400 @ 3.10GHz
        Sandy Bridge 32nm Technology
    RAM
        8.00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 665MHz
    Motherboard
        Dell Inc. 0D28YY (CPU 1)
    Graphics
        S22C300 (1920x1080@60Hz)
        S22C300 (1920x1080@60Hz)
        512MB ATI AMD Radeon HD 6350 (HP)
    Storage
        465GB Seagate ST3500413AS (SATA)
        465GB ADATA NH01 USB Device (USB)
```

Comment: Welcome to SU!  Sorry to hear about your troubles, but what's your specific question to us?  What have you tried already?  What were the results?

Comment: I haven't been able to really find any possible solutions, so all I can say I've tried is restart and checking if there were any updates. My question would be whats possibly causing it and what can I do to remedy it? Thanks!

Comment: Is [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/104032-system-very-unstable-flashing-shaking.html) the same issue? Does switching to Windows classic theme help? Of so, maybe the solution on that page (disabling the "Desktop Windows Manage Service") help.

Comment: No, I am able to stop it just by killing Outlook. :0(

Comment: I still feel it could be the same underlying problem. I don't have any other suggestions than to try the classic theme of Windows. If that doesn't help I'm all out of ideas.